# Empty mutable collection(List) of generic type in kotlin

Tags: collections, kotlin

How to declare an empty mutable collection(List) of generic type in kotlin?

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [Kotlin reference regarding Collections: List, Set, Map](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collections.html).
The following will create an empty mutable list of your desired type:

```
val yourCollection = mutableListOf<YourType>()
```

If you rather meant a mutable `Collection<List<YourType>>`, then maybe the following will help you:

```
val mutableCollectionWithList : Collection<List<YourType>> = mutableListOf(mutableListOf())
```

Alternatively if you do not really need an empty list you can also do:

```
val yourCollection = mutableListOf(YourType(), ...)
```

And if you rather want an empty list which is not mutable, use the following instead:

```
val emptyList = emptyList<YourType>()
```